# How can I manage OAuth refresh tokens with Laravel?

Tags: laravel, oauth, laravel-5.1, google-api-php-client, laravel-socialite

The Socialiate plugin provides an implementation for OAuth in Laravel, but it seems to be designed for mostly for the purpose of allowing them to not have to make a user account on your own site.

I am making an application that helps manage their Youtube account, meaning the scope of the auth request is broader (which was easy to change) but I also need a refresh token (versus just an access token) for long-term access to their account.

Is there a package out there for Laravel that already handles this? I haven't been able to find one, but maybe I'm searching for the wrong thing.

If not, how should I approach this? When I write my code that interacts with Youtube's API, do I simply need to check whether the access token is expired, and if so, write a function that does an HTTP request to get a new one with the refresh token I have stored in the database? And I guess also extend Socialite to retrieve a refresh token?

I feel like there's got to be a better way that doesn't involve me re-inventing the wheel.

Answer (score 26):

It's been a while since this question was last visited, and seeing that it is the first Google result, I'd like to say: **This is now possible with Socialite.**

When you redirect your users to Google, set `access_type` to `offline` with the `with()` method when redirecting, like this:

```
    return Socialite::driver('google')
        ->scopes() // For any extra scopes you need, see https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/googlescopes for a full list; alternatively use constants shipped with Google's PHP Client Library
        ->with(["access_type" => "offline", "prompt" => "consent select_account"])
        ->redirect();
```

This will make Google return a refresh token.

Comment: This should be top answer tbh

Comment: But socialite cannot use the refresh token out of the box to refresh the user token, right?

Answer (score 2):

This is difficult to find information for, partially because of the OAuth2-server package for Laravel to provide its own OAuth solution which is most of the search results.

I think the best answer is going to be writing your own YoutubeProvider for Socialite. Here's a tutorial: https://medium.com/laravel-news/adding-auth-providers-to-laravel-socialite-ca0335929e42#.6bn8i2wz4

It will be a pain to change Socialite to start working with refresh tokens, so I think the best route will be for the YoutubeProvider to have an additional call to a new getRefreshToken function at the end of the existing getAccessToken function. Change both the access and refresh tokens to save the retrieved token to the database, because Socialite will not give you the option to access the refresh token to save it in a helper/controller class.

Create a Tokens model and database table, and store both access and refresh tokens in there with a relationship to a User model.

When you write your YoutubeService helper, it will need to be able to attempt an API call with an access token and know to refresh it with the refresh token if it receives the error message that it's expired/invalid.

The Google's API library for PHP seems to handle this automatically with `$client->setAccessType("offline")`: https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/php/auth/web-app

but as soon as you start needing refresh tokens for something other than Google, you'll be writing that code anyway if the new provider doesn't also have a library. On the upside, this library has a Service specifically for Youtube, so it should handle all the API calls to Youtube that you may need. I am not sure entirely how using this library will mesh with Socialite, since Socialite seems to already do a lot of what this library does. You might wind up making some sort of redundant authorization within your YoutubeService class unless you really want to start customizing things.

It might be worth considering removing Socialite from the equation entirely and using Google's library when it comes to their services.